# Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in C:\xamp\htdocs\project24\system\database\DB_driver.php on line 768

Tags: mysql, migration, fatal-error

Dear all I am getting error when i am trying to create a table through Migration.
I am getting following **error**:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean 
 in C:\xamp\htdocs\project24\system\database\DB_driver.php on line 768
```

**My code is:**

```
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            if (isset($row['TABLE_NAME']))
            {
                $retval[] = $row['TABLE_NAME'];
            }
            else
            {
                $retval[] = array_shift($row);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->data_cache['table_names'] = $retval;
    $ex=$this->data_cache['table_names'];
    return $ex;
}
```

**Line Number 768**

[image]

Please Help me to get out from this error

Answer (score 0):

i'll suppose that $query is the result of sending query and getting response. I'll explain it with more appropiate var names:

```
if($result = connection()->query($query)) $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Ok, at this point you have the first row on $rs, it doesn't matter if $rs is void here. Remember that if you use a CREATE sentence, mysql engine will return void (0 cols) result, so php can take it as true (if table created) or false (if not), so it's a boolean. In the case you make a select on there, and you want to do something in a loop, you will follow as this:

```
while ($rs != ''){

//do something with $rs[index];

$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//to take next row
}
connection()-close();
```

hope it helps. Cheers!